# How to write only once to file from a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to write something to the end of the file every time the file is modified and I'm using this code :

```
public class Main {

    public static final String DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "D:\\test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path toWatch = Paths.get(DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH);
        if (toWatch == null) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        try {
            WatchService myWatcher = toWatch.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
            FileWatcher fileWatcher = new FileWatcher(myWatcher);
            Thread t = new Thread(fileWatcher, "FileWatcher");
            t.start();
            toWatch.register(myWatcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
            t.join();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and the thread class :

```
public class FileWatcher implements Runnable{
    private WatchService myWatcher;
    private Path toWatch;
    String content = "Dong\n";
    int counter = 0;

    public FileWatcher (WatchService myWatcher, Path toWatch) {
    this.myWatcher = myWatcher;
    this.toWatch = toWatch;
}
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            WatchKey key = myWatcher.take();
            while (key != null) {
                for (WatchEvent event : key.pollEvents()) {
                    //System.out.printf("Received %s event for file: %s\n", event.kind(), event.context());
                    //System.out.println(counter);
                    myWatcher = null;
                    File file = new File(Main.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH + "\\" + event.context());
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                    fw.write(counter + content);
                    fw.close();
                    counter++;
                    myWatcher = toWatch.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
                    toWatch.register(myWatcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
//                  BufferedWriter bwWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);
//                  bwWriter.write(content);
//                  bwWriter.close();
                }
                key.reset();
                key = myWatcher.take();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I want to get in the file something like :

```
acasc 0dong
dwqcacesv 1dong
terert 2dong
```

However, now I'm getting this, because it writes too many times in the file:

```
acasc 0dong
1dong
...
50123dong
```

If I use `System.out.println(counter);` it works as I want to (prints the number of file changes correctly), but it goes wild on `fw.write(counter + content);`

Comment: It sounds like you're monitoring a file for changes, and when changes are detected you write something to the end of the file, which causes changes to be detected so you write something to the end of the file, which causes changes to be detected so you write something to the end of the file, which causes changes to be detected...

Comment: I think you'll have to disable the file watcher if you want to append data to the file only once after the update occurs, if I'm understanding your requirements properly. Otherwise, your code is inducing a change that the FIleWatcher catches, and that's why it's "going wild.."

Comment: ...and in the meantime, those changes might get interleaved with what other  threads write into the file, unless you have an exclusive lock on them.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread's write is causing further changes to the file.
Self feeding loop.